# Data Service Server (DSS) && SQL Server: How to handle exceptions (RaiserError)

Tags: sql-server, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

In SQL Server a procedure was developed that at one point returns an exception with `RAISERROR`.

When this occurs, the DSS is thrown "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException."

Is it possible handle the exception to be shown the same message thrown by the database, because that way it would be possible to know the type of error that occurred and not only "XMLStreamException"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the data service usually it is created with streaming enable. When the streaming is enabled it will not construct the payload and just stream hence may occur this error. You can disable the streaming by [unchecking the box in the Dataservice](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/RDBMS) or defining and attribute in the data service.

```
disableStreaming=true
```